# How to set number of grid lines in nvd3 (angular wrapper)?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am having a nvd3-line-chart using the angular wrapper [angularjs-nvd3-directives](http://cmaurer.github.io/angularjs-nvd3-directives/line.chart.html):

```
<nvd3-line-chart
  data="data"
  height="300"
  rescaleY="true"
  forceY="[1]"
  tooltips="true"
  interactive="true"  
  clipVoronoi="true"
  showLegend="true"
  showXAxis="true"
  showYAxis="true">
</nvd3-line-chart>
```

I would like to set the number of grid lines on the x-axis to a constant value. I tried to do this with the attribute:

```
xAxisTicks="5"
```

However, this has no effect. The number of grid lines is always the same (automatically set). Doing similar things like e.g. changing the tick-format (with `xAxisTickFormat=xxx`) does what is expected. I tried debugging this (setting of xaxisticks) but without success.

If anyone knows more about this, I'd appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe there are 2 ways:

1. Using xAxisTickFormatFunction(), you can define your funciton for xAxis value format. In thin function, you can map the x value into a fixed ranged data, then during display xAxis, the number of tickets of xAxis will be fixed.
2. Using `Force X`, set a value like `[100, 200]`. You need to make sure all x values are in this range.

Comment: Sorry, for the late answer. I didn't quite get 1), but 2) had no effect (strangely this works on the y-axis but not on the x-axis). After a while I just used a different library. Thanks for your advice anyways.